# Multiple BackgroundWorker throws timeout exception

Tags: wpf, multithreading, timeout, httpwebrequest, backgroundworker

If I keep two FileDownload (find code in below link) in Pause mode and if I start 3rd third instance of Filedownload, I am getting timeout error.

I am working on a WPF application where I need to download multiple .zip files from a CDN server. I am using following code to download file.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35954/C-NET-Background-File-Downloader?msg=5402177#xx5402177xx

In my case I have to download multiple files simultaneously and to show progress for each file downloading. I am creating an instance of FileDownloader (find code in below link) class each time when user downloads a file.

I am facing operation timeout error, when I am keeping two instances of FileDownloader on Puase mode and when I start 3rd instance. The 3rd instance continuously waiting at webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse(); and after sometime it throws operation timeout error.

If I try to download same zip files through chrome browser, and if keep first to on pause still the 3rd file getting downloaded.

Any suggestions, how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please give us a [mcve]. Don't just provide some links, but show us your relevant code. (BTW, don't use `BackgroundWorkers`, unless you're stuck with .NET 2.0. Use TPL instead.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided the piece of code troubling me. I have created another question with as minimal details as possible. Hope now it's easy to understand the problem. Here is the link for question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364652/multiple-backgroundworker-throws-operation-timeout-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue, by default the number of connection an application can open are 2 but with below line of code you can set it to higher number. It can also be done in app.config

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 65000;
```